# Using PHP functions in MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, pdo

Can I use my own functions from PHP directly in SQL queries (using **mySQL** and **PDO**)? For example:

```
$query  = null;
$result = null;
$query  = $this->database_0->prepare("SELECT `id`, `salt` FROM `general_users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = CONCAT(generatePassword(:password, `salt`)) LIMIT 1");
$query->bindValue(':username', $this->input->getValue('username'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':password', $this->input->getValue('password'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query->closeCursor();
```

*Look at line 3 in "WHERE" case.*

If it is not possible, I must use two queries just for check if a user exists, it do not look very optimal.

Thanks for your help, Bartek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use my own functions from PHP directly in SQL queries

No. 
Mysql knows nothing of PHP and its functions. You are bound to use mysql functions in mysql and PHP functions in PHP. Quite easy to memorize.

So, here you go, with one single query

```
$sql  = "SELECT id, salt, password FROM general_users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$this->input->getValue('username')]);
$row = $query->fetch();

if (generatePassword($row['password'], $row['salt']) == $this->input->getValue('password'))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a PHP function in a MySQL query.

You can still do this with a single query. Just retrieve user info (including password) by comparing only its `username`. Then, in PHP, compare stored password with the one you have just computed. That would even allow you to distinguish two cases: *"user exists, but password is wrong"* and *"user does not exist*".

Comment: Merci Guillaume. (je parle français)

That I need it's to select user password and his "salt", after, with "generatePassword" function I generate the good password [it add the selected salt using some new PHP 5 (>= 5.1.2) functions].

So I need two queries:
- one for select the salt, then I use my function directly in PHP code;
- the second for check if a user with this password exists;